# Service Virtualization with JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2, service-virtualization

I am using JMeter for API Testing.  Using HTTP Request and Beanshell I am able to achieve this.

There are times where the Services are down for a weeks time.

Since I the have the Request and Response with me, I would like to implement Service Virtualization using JMeter.

Even when the Services are down, I should be able to continue my testing.

Can I achieve Service Virtualization in JMeter? If yes, can I request you to let me know the steps please.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't.

I suggest you check out [API simulation tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_API_simulation_tools) which will allow you to do service virtualization. You can then use JMeter to run your tests and an API simulation tool to mock the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

JMeter doesn't do Service Virtualization, but you can use JMeter in recording, see [article](https://www.infoq.com/articles/stubbing-mocking-service-virtualization-differences):

> You can import the incoming traffic to JMeter using tcpreplay and
>   JMeter Proxy. Run a test suite in your performance environment using
>   JMeter and use the virtual services to decouple yourself from other
>   dependencies. Just to be safe, repeat the recording process every
>   week. This could prove to be very easy or very difficult to implement
>   depending on the specifics of the system you are working with.

Comment: Many thanks for your response.

My HTTP Request in hitting a URL with the port 

Eg :

https://apitesting.com:8888/api/series/one

I have also added a HTTP Test Script Recorder in JMeter, where I can mention the port and domain.

How do I import the incoming traffic to JMeter using tcpreplay and JMeter Proxy for the above example.

Comment: I suggest you open a new question for specific case